# Error 40 al conectar Power BI con localhost de Wampserver64

Tags: mysql, wamp, powerbi

Buenas tengo el siguiente error cuando quiero levantar mi base de datos "comentario" desde PowerBI.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Información de interés:

- El servidor y bases de datos están creados con WampServer 64 bits.
- Ya intente la solución de microsoft de el usuario y contraselña en el origen de datos
- Tengo instalado el SQL Connector 10.7

Aguardo gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue: 
descargar el SQL Connector, instalarlo y en vez de utilizar la carga de datos por SQL Server usé la opción Base de datos MySQL en power bi.